# Uncaught RangeError; Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: jquery, typeerror

I'm trying to list data from a JSON source.

I loop the data in a `$.each`, and display it using `append`.

```
var result = JSON.parse(response);

if(result.count != 0) {
    $(".modal").find("#search-results").html("<p>" + result.count + " result(s) found:</p>");
    var list = $(".modal").find("#search-results").append("<div class=\"list-group dbsearch-list-group\"></div>").find('div');
    $.each(result.results, function(index, value) {
        var link = list.append('<a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item p-0 list-group-item-action" id="autosearch" data-id="' + value.itemid + '" data-instantclose="true"></a>').find('a');
        var col = link.append('<div class="row"></div>').find('div');
            col.append('<div class="col-sm py-0 col-md-auto"><img src="' + value.icon + '" class="dbsearch-icon" /></div>');
            col.append('<div class="col-sm py-0 align-self-center">' + value.title + '</div>');
    });
} else {
    $(".modal").find("#search-results").html("<p>No results found.</p>");
}
```

For some odd reason, it outputs an error after a couple of loops:

> jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

[image]

I've Googled the error and they say it's caused by an infinite loop. The JSON response entries can be quite long, around 300 items.

Even then, it shouldn't really output this if I'm correct. Why is this happening?

Comment: It's caused by infinite recursion, not an infinite loop.

Comment: If you look in the call stack in the JavaScript debugger you should see what function is being called repeatedly.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, where do I find this?

Comment: In the Sources tab of Developer Tools.

Comment: @Barmar I've paused the page after it froze: https://i.imgur.com/bICsdeo.png

Comment: Is this code running inside an event handler? What event?

Comment: @Barmar ```$(document).on('submit', '#dbsearch', function(event) {```

Comment: To get infinite recursion you would have to trigger the same event while processing the result. I'm not sure how that would happen, especially since events are asynchronous.

Comment: You need to scroll down in the call stack to see if you can see some repetition in the calls.

Comment: @Barmar I've tried it multiple times now but it keeps outputting what's shown in the previous picture

Comment: @Barmar Sorry for the second ping. When commenting out the code inside the `$.each`, it loops correctly. So there's something going wrong with the append.

Comment: Each time through the `$.each` loop, `link` will be a collection of all the `<a>` elements that you've appended to `list` so far. Is that really what you want? I suspect you just want it to be the one you appended in that iteration.

Comment: `link = list.append("some html").find("a")` is equivalent to `list.append("some html"); link = list.find("a");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your chained functions of the form:

```
x = y.append("some HTML element").find("type of that element");
```

are doing what you expect. I think you're trying to set `x` to the element that you just appended. But it actually sets it to a collection of *all* the elements that have been appended so far. And when `y` is one of these collections, you're appending the new HTML to all of them, and then finding all of the elements that have been appended that way. This is causing exponential explosion of the number of elements being created and appended.

What I think you want is this:

```
x = $("some HTML element").appendTo(y);
```

So the full code should be:

```
var result = JSON.parse(response);

if(result.count != 0) {
    $(".modal").find("#search-results").html("<p>" + result.count + " result(s) found:</p>");
    var list = $("<div class=\"list-group dbsearch-list-group\"></div>").appendTo(".modal");
    $.each(result.results, function(index, value) {
        var link = $('<a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item p-0 list-group-item-action" id="autosearch" data-id="' + value.itemid + '" data-instantclose="true"></a>').appendTo(list);
        var col = $('<div class="row"></div>').appendTo(link);
        col.append('<div class="col-sm py-0 col-md-auto"><img src="' + value.icon + '" class="dbsearch-icon" /></div>');
        col.append('<div class="col-sm py-0 align-self-center">' + value.title + '</div>');
    });
} else {
    $(".modal").find("#search-results").html("<p>No results found.</p>");
}
```

Comment: Yep, totally works! Appreciate the help a lot, Barmar!